# Disposing a control by calling its own BeginInvoke()

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading, controls, dispose

Disposing a control from by calling its own BeginInvoke() is a good idea or bad idea? Or shall I use the parent control or something like that to accomplish this task?

*I'm using Invoke because I'm accessing the control form another thread.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see why it should be a bad idea. Invoke or BeginInvoke does not do any special tricks other than calling the method on the right thread.

Comment: So it doesn't matter which control I use to call Invoke it will just switch to that context and run it. Is that right?

Comment: In general I think it is a good idea to call `Invoke` on the control on which you want to invoke the delegate passed to the `Invoke` statement, but for practical reasons *I don't think* it matters, as long as the control that you call `Invoke` on is owned by the same thread as the target control.

Comment: Great answer thanks, although you said "I think", I'll take it as you are sure :)

Comment: @dr. evil: you take is as you want, *I think* only means that it's your insurance kicking in if something goes wrong, not mine ;o)